# GitLab-CI Multi Runner php composer cache

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab-ci-multi-runner with docker containers. Everything is going fine, but docker containers don't keep the `composer` cache so in every run `composer` downloads dependencies again and again, which takes a lot of time. Is there any way to configure `gitlab-ci-runner` docker container to keep the `composer` cache or mount a volume on each run where the `composer` cache is kept?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could modify the composer cache path and write the stuff to a docker volume.

That storage is persistent and can be shared across containers.

Referencing:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#volumes-in-the-runnersdocker-section
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/

Answer (score 37):

You can change the composer cache path by exporting the [`COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-cache-dir) environment variable in your [runner configuration](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runners-section) file, and then add a volume in the [`[runners.docker]`](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section) section to match it.

If you run gitlab-runner as root or with sudo, then your configuration file is located at `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`. Otherwise it's located at `$HOME/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

```
# config.toml

[[runners]]
  name = "Generic Docker Runner"
  ...
  environment = ["COMPOSER_CACHE_DIR=/cache"]
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    ...
    volumes = ["/var/cache:/cache:rw"]
    cache_dir = "/cache"
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks! Seeing these packages downloading again and again was getting really irritating.